# Scripting within Jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

**Main problem:**

In the Jenkins build, I have a variable `GIT_BRANCH` of this content: `origin/feature/JIRA1-add-component-A`.

From it I would like to obtain another variable with the value: `%3Aorigin%2Ffeature%2FJIRA1-add-component-A`

For this, I need scripting. How can I do scripting in the job definition?

**Context & further explanation:**

From Jenkins, for every pull request that my project has, I am creating an instance of a project in SonarQube.

For example, if I have a pull request from branch `origin/feature/JIRA1-add-component-A`, I am creating a project with the following URL:

http://localhost:9000/dashboard?id=com.my.package%3Amy-project%3Aorigin%2Ffeature%2FJIRA1-add-component-A

I am using the Quality Gates plugin to fail the build in case the code's quality(as seen by SonarQube)is not good.

The problem is that Quality Gates needs my SonarQube project name, so in this case `com.my.package%3Amy-project%3Aorigin%2Ffeature%2FJIRA1-add-component-A`.

However, I can only specify it like this:

```
com.my.package:my-project:${GIT_BRANCH}
```

Which translates into this:

```
com.my.package:my-project:origin/feature/JIRA1-add-component-A
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? Apologize if not, but dead tired lol.

```
def GIT_BRANCH = "origin/feature/JIRA1-add-component-A"
def BRANCH = "%A3" + "${GIT_BRANCH}".replace("/", "%2F")
println "${BRANCH}"
```

I'm sure it can be done easier BUT:

Pre:  origin/feature/JIRA1-add-component-A

Post: %A3origin%2Ffeature%2FJIRA1-add-component-A

Comment: So where exactly in the job configuration can I put this?

Comment: That's my bad I thought you were using pipeline: There are multiple ways to do this, this being one and using some sed magic to set your environment variable, but I would have to see exactly how this job is setup to help more. I apologize.

Install: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Environment+Script+Plugin

and as the script